# MS Access - return values by max date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm lost on this one, I'm a bit of a newcomer to Access and SQL, I have scoured the site and Google for the answer to this one.

I have a table with 3 columns containing IDs to other tables and then a date.

Column 1 (RoleID) Column 2 (ActionID) Column 3 (SettingID) Column 4 (Date)

I need to group by Column 1 and Column 2 (so the unique combinations of these). There may be multiple instances with different SettingID, differentiated by a date.

I think a Totals select query does the job, with Group by for Column1 and 2, then using Max for the date column. However I just want the value of Column 3, not a total.

Is there a simple way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Thank you for helping! Seems I need to learn a bit more theory of SQL as the answer makes perfect sense, I was trying to build it using design mode of a query - I cannot see how one would create this query using design mode in Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select roleid, actionid, settingid
from your_table t1
inner join
(
   select roleid, actionid, max(date) as mdate
   from your_table
   group by roleid, actionid
) t2 on t1.roleid = t2.roleid 
    and t1.actionid = t2.actionid
    and t1.date = t2.mdate
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply juergen :) I am using Access 2007 and when I try to save your suggestion it says 'Syntax error in FROM clause' and then highlights JOIN.

Comment: Is this a Select query or is t2 meant to be a table that is being created as a result of this sql?

Comment: `t2` is an alias name for the subquery.

Comment: @JeffHowarth trying putting [ ] between the two tables names in the query?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a really old version of Access then it won't support Subqueries very well

You can work round this by creating a seperate query

```
select roleid, actionid, max(date) as mdate
from your_table
group by roleid, actionid
```

Save it as MaxDateQuery or something similar

Then you can use that saved Access query in a subsequent query to get what you wannt

```
select 
your_table.roleid, 
your_table.actionid, 
your_table.settingid
from your_table
inner join MaxDateQuery 
on  your_table.roleid   = MaxDateQuery.roleid 
and your_table.actionid = MaxDateQuery.actionid
and your_table.date     = MaxDateQuery.mdate
```